# Wordpress blog url is redirecting to uknown url's if I access from hyperlink?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress blog is not working from hyperlink, redirecting to unknown urls(http://redirect.xmlheads.com/index.php?aid=6489&auth=3910569b5b&q=wordpress+-&ref=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fblog.wordpress.com%2F&step=2 
and https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=KiqfV7z0EMyDuATnvZKYCw&gws_rd=ssl)
Example: 
Blog

If I use direclty  blog.wordpress.com/http://blog.wordpress.com from the borwser then page is loading without any issues. Previously there was no issues, but now I am facing the issue with hyperlink / indirect access to that url.

Comment: Have you used site_url() in your hyperlinks ?

Comment: Like this I am using <a href="http://blog.wordpres.com" target="_blank">Blog</a>

Comment: Trying hard coding the url with appending http:// and then followed by the domain name. I would suggest you to use the site_url(), this function is provided by wordpress in order to locate the path in which wordpress is installed.

Comment: I am using hyperlink for wordpress site from cakephp not in wordpress.

Comment: have you tried hardcoding the url 
For Ex: if your url is abc.com/page1 , <a href="http://www.example.com/page1">, Also you can check the url helper of cakephp http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html

Comment: Issue is solved, Issue was not with the url . Some unwanted script is addedd to wordpress by bots because of this  url is redirecting to random url.  So removed the unwanted script and updated wordpress with latest version .